# How to display WPF's XAML element in class diagram

Tags: wpf, xaml, class-diagram

I have a WPF project, in MainWindow there are some controls

```
<Button/> 
<TextBox/>
```

How can I get them displayed in class diagram like this?

[image]

I know in WinForm it works, but how about in WPF?

Answer (score 1):

The class diagram as you present it works with fields declared in the form class. WPF will not automatically generate a backing field for a WPF control unless you name it. E.g.

```
<Button Name="MyButton" />
```

Creates a field called `MyButton` in the class where you declare it.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that this is the only solution.